# How to I declare and initialize a multidimensional array in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

I want to do this:

```
Dim Numbers As Integer()() = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}}
```

The IDE's underlining `4, 5, 6, 7` and saying `Array initializer has 3 too many elements`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/wak0wfyt.aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following should work:

```
Dim Numbers As Integer()() = {({1}), ({2}), ({3}), ({4, 5, 6, 7})}
```

As documents in [Arrays in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/wak0wfyt.aspx):

> You can avoid an error when you supply nested array literals of different dimensions by enclosing the inner array literals in parentheses. The parentheses force the array literal expression to be evaluated, and the resulting values are used with the outer array literal

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why all I was missing were those parens.  Thanks, it worked awesomely.