# Declaring multidimensional array

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

I want to loop into an array and fill some data. But I have not been able to find out, how to declare a multidimensional array when I don't know the width in advance.

Here's what I have right now.

```
Dim Items()() As String
        For y As Integer = 0 To object.Count - 1
            Items(y)(0) = "something"
            Items(y)(1) = "something"
            Items(y)(2) = "something"
            Items(y)(3) = "something"
            Items(y)(4) = "something"
            Items(y)(5) = "something"
            Items(y)(6) = "something"
 Next
```

I've been suggested to do it with (X, X) but I'm not sure how to declare this without a width.
How should I do this?

Comment: What you've declared is a jagged array, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkhhsz9t(v=vs.90).aspx, where what you've been suggested to do is create a 2d array, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sxy840k(v=vs.90).aspx.

Comment: Putting more links into the @Shar1er80's comment, what you've declared is a [jagged array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14990561/11683), where what you've been suggested to do is create a [2d array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26111008/11683).

Comment: Have you tought of using a List(Of SomeClass) instead? Especially if each "something" represent a different property.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want a 2-dimensional array to keep track of multiple arrays of Strings. If you know the total count of the arrays you will have, you could do this:

```
Dim Items(object.Count - 1, 6) As String
For y As Integer = 0 To object.Count - 1
    Items(y, 0) = "something"
    Items(y, 1) = "something"
    Items(y, 2) = "something"
    Items(y, 3) = "something"
    Items(y, 4) = "something"
    Items(y, 5) = "something"
    Items(y, 6) = "something"
Next
```

Honestly it would be better to use a `List (Of List(Of String))`, as multidimensional arrays have to have the first index's upper bound declared when you initialize it. The second indexes upper bound can be redimmed.

Using the list setup would be something like:

```
Dim Items As New List(Of List(Of String))
For y As Integer = 0 To object.Count - 1
    Dim tmpList As New List(Of String)
    tmpList.Add("something")
    tmpList.Add("something")
    tmpList.Add("something")
    tmpList.Add("something")
    tmpList.Add("something")
    tmpList.Add("something")
    tmpList.Add("something")
    Items.Add(tmpList)
Next
```

Or, better yet, as the_lotus mentioned in the comments above, create a class if possible to hold the 7 (or however many) values going into the inner list or array, then you only need a `List(Of String)` to hold each instance.

Comment: +1 on the Multi-Dimensional array (if that's truly what you want); that is the correct format for declaring/using it.